# Xcode repetitive installations

Tags: macos, homebrew, xcode

Xcode releases usually follow macOS releases. Until recently macOS Sonoma updated and I have to reinstall all my Xcode packages or simulators again. In addition to linking brew over again to recognize the next dev environment state. I wonder is this an expected issue or a misconfiguration with the user symbol and staff materials?

Answer (score 0):

The post [Xcode not working on macOS Sonoma](https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/731005)
has these advice from people that managed to get Xcode 14.3.1
working with Sonoma.

I can't test these, but only list them :

> 1. I solved the problem uninstalling Xcode 15 and installing the 14.3, after that, I set the "/Application/Xcode.app" in the "Location:" field in the *Visual Studio > preferences > SDK Locations > Apple*. Then I clicked in Restart Visual Studio button and worked.
> 2. actually Xcode 14.3.1 is able to work on Sonoma. Just launch it from package contents `Contents/MacOS/Xcode`.